# Tratar ArithmeticException em outro método

Tags: java

quero criar um método divide(double a, double b) que tenha try/catch pra pegar a Arithmetic Exception, retornando uma mensagem de erro por System.out.println; como não é no método main, não sei como tem que ser a assinatura do método, retorno, etc. Precisava de algo assim:

```
public static ? divide(double dividendo, double divisor){
    try{
    return dividendo/divisor;
    } 
    catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Erro: divisão por zero!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode deixar o retorno como double mesmo `public static double divide`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tentar pegar uma ArithmeticException de divisao por 0 (**com doubles**) em Java não vai dar resultado. Pois, java implementa o padrão [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) para o tipo double. Logo, ao invés de exceção, voce tera um valor que representa infinito.

Em resumo:

Isso acontece porque o padrão 754 encoraja que os programas sejam mais robustos.

A IEEE 754 define X/0.0 como "Infinity",-X/0.0 como "-Infinity" e 0/0 como "NaN".

Se quiser tratar esse caso:

```
//throws declara que o metodo lanca excecao... forcando o programador a envolver esse método em um try-catch
public static double divide(double dividendo, double divisor) throws ArithmeticException{
    if(divisor == 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("O divisor nao pode ser 0 !");
    return dividendo/divisor;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode deixar o `double` como retorno na assinatura e lançar uma exceção personalizada e capturá-la no seu *main*, exibindo a mensagem:

```
public static double divide(double dividendo, double divisor){
  if(divisor != 0){
    return dividendo/divisor;
  } 
  else {
    throw new DivisaoPorZeroException("Erro: divisão por zero!");
  }
}
```

Você também precisa criar a Classe de Exceção `MinhaExcecao`:

```
public class DivisaoPorZeroException extends RuntimeException {

    public DivisaoPorZeroException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Depois, basta capturar a exceção usando `try/catch` no *main* e exibir a mensagem usando o `System.out.println()`

Lembrando que criar exceções é opcional e deve ser usado apenas se houver necessidade de lançar exceções mais especificas. Sempre prefira evitar que a exceção aconteça, corrigindo aquilo que possa lançá-la, que no seu caso, seria impedir que seja informado divisor com valor 0.

Sugiro a leitura [**desta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186670/28595) para melhores esclarecimentos

Comment: Usando esse código eu recebo o erro "Construtor MinhaExcecao in class MinhaExcecao cannot be applied to given types"

Comment: @Ana complementei minha resposta, além de criar a classe MinhaExcecao, você também precisa criar um construtor que receba uma String.