# Boas práticas com tratamento de exceção Java

Tags: java, exceção

Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com mais de uma exceção no Java?

No código abaixo, eu vejo a possibilidade de dar dois erros `NullPointer` ou `SQLException`. Se eu colocar um `catch` para cada exceção é a melhor maneira?

```
public Boolean cadastro(Contato contato) throws SQLException, ExceptionCadastro {
    try {
        PreparedStatement p = (PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement("insert into contatos (nome, email, telefone, endereco) values (?,?,?,?)");
        p.setString(1, contato.getNome());
        p.setString(2, contato.getEmail());
        p.setString(3, contato.getTelefone());
        p.setString(4, contato.getEndereco());
        p.executeUpdate();
        p.close();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        conexao.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: nullpointer deve ser detectado e corrigido, não capturado. Nunca vi caso onde capturar é a melhor opção. Se há risco de dados nulos, deve ser feita uma validação condicional, não capturar nullpointer.

Comment: Quanto a exceções de conexão, recomendo fortemente a leitura:[Como funciona o try-with-resources?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/28595)

Comment: Certo Diego, concordo contigo, eu apenas usei nullpointer como exemplo.

Comment: Este código compila? Não deveria porque tem situação que ele não retorna nada, sei lá se o Java assume algum padrão. De resto é o que o @diegofm falou. Mas se fosse dois erros que deveriam ser capturados, depende se você quer fazer a mesma coisa ou coisas diferentes, e só deve capturar o que vai fazer alguma coisa útil. Quase sempre imprimir o *stacktrace* ou coisa do tipo não é algo útil, esse tratamento deveria ocorrer no `main()` ou algo assim. A maior parte das capturas que os programadores fazem não deveriam ser feitas.

Comment: Veja mais em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: @bigown O código não tem lá muita qualidade, mas compila sim. Ele sempre retorna `true` se uma exceção não tiver sido lançada (o que significa que o retorno não serve para muita coisa nesse caso). É interessante notar que ele retorna `true` mesmo se ocorrer um `NullPointerException` dentro do `try`!

Comment: Sim Victor, eu arrumei isso hehe. 

Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como já foi dito nos comentários, erros de programação como o `NullPointerException` nunca devem ser capturados, eles devem ser corrigidos. Idealmente ele só deve ocorrer durante seus testes no desenvolvimento. Então o melhor a fazer é quebrar a aplicação para que você possa consertar o problema.

Só capture exceções que você possa fazer alguma coisa útil e se recuperar daquele erro. Erros de programação ou mesmo os erros de ambiente (provocados pela JVM direta ou indiretamente) não possui tratamento. Mesmo uma `ArithmeticException` é um erro de programação, você não deveria deixar um cálculo dar um erro.

Aí entramos em uma certa polêmica. A cultura do Java indica que na maioria dos casos onde uma operação pode dar um problema deva gerar uma exceção e ela deve ser tratada para se recuperar (isso tem mudado desde o Java 8, alguns programadores não perceberam isso).

Em outras culturas é mais comum seguir o caminho de tentar evitar o erro antes que ele aconteça ou [verificar o erro de uma outra forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101) (o próprio Java opta por isto em vários pontos) que não seja a exceção.

Nos casos onde dá para verificar o erro de outra forma ou dá para evitá-lo eu sempre prefiro esse caminho, a maioria dos programadores Java ainda preferem deixar a exceção ocorrer, mesmo sendo uma [opção mais lenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101). Tem situações que só a exceção é o adequado. Mas isso está mudando e os programadores têm adotado outras técnicas cada vez mais.

Nos casos que deve mesmo capturar a exceção, só o faça no local onde pode resolver algo. Mesmo que este algo seja só mostrar uma mensagem para o usuário ou *logar* o erro em algum lugar. Se não pode resolver o problema ou fazer algo útil pra que capturar a exceção?

Quase sempre imprimir o *stack trace* ou fazer algo equivalente significa que a aplicação desistiu e vai quebrar, ou pelo menos voltar ao seu início. Pra que ficar capturando exceção no código todo pra fazer a mesma coisa? Deixa a exceção borbulhar para a pilha de chamada e só trate em um local neutro.

Minhas aplicações costumam ter bem menos `catch`es que a maioria das aplicações em Java por aí, em alguns casos a diferença chega aos milhares.

E se tiver um `throw` dentro de um `catch` quase sempre é um erro.

Se você realmente precisa tratar mais de uma exceção naquele mesmo local tem duas estratégias:

- A ação a ser tomada é a mesma, faça um `catch` com o operador de OR para aceitar qualquer uma delas:

  ```
  try { 
      ...
  } catch (ExceptionCadastro | SQLException ex) { 
      ...
  }
  ```
- Se precisa que cada erro tenha uma ação diferente utilize mais de um `catch`:

  ```
  try { 
      ...
  } catch (ExceptionCadastro) { 
      ...
  } catch (SQLException ex) { 
      ...
  }
  ```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/MultipleCatches.java).

E [não vá capturar `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101) a não ser que saiba o que está fazendo.

Pode [ler mais sobre o assunto no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Recomendo muito, a maioria dos programadores não entendem e abusam de exceções.