# Não é possível encontrar a tabela 0 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela que exporta dados processados de uma `Procedure` para PDF/Xls. Depurando ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível encontrar a tabela 0

Pelo o que eu entendi ele não consegue ler a classe instanciada em um objeto. Gostaria de saber o que pode causar esse tipo de erro que eu mencionei.

Segue códigos:

**Evento de importar XLS**( o tipo de relatório que eu estou usando é o "**saldoest**"):

```
 protected void btnImpListaXLS_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Estoque objEstoque = new Estoque();
        switch (ddlTipoRelatorio.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "saldo":
                SetarFiltrosRptSaldoAtualEstoque();
                break;
            case "curva":
                objEstoque.ProcessarProcRelCurvaABC(SetarFiltroCurvaABC());
                break;
            case "esgotados":
                objEstoque.ProcessarProcEsgotados(SertarFiltroEsgostados());
                break;
            case "movimentacao":
                switch (rdbMovimentacao.SelectedValue)
                {
                    case "analitico":
                        SetarParametroMovimentacaoAnalitica();
                        break;
                    case "sintetico":
                        objEstoque.ProcessarRelatorioMovimentacaoSintetica(SetarParametroMovimentacaoSintetico(objEstoque));
                        break;
                    case "notasFiscais":
                        SetarParametroMovimentacaoNotasFiscais();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "custoVendas":
                objEstoque.ProcessarRelatorioCustoVendas(SetarFiltrosCustoVendas());
                break;
            case "valProd":
                ProcessarValidadeProdutos(objEstoque, "xls");
                return;
            case "saldoest":
                objEstoque.ProcessarSaldoAtualEstoqueEmpresa(SetarFiltrosEstoqueEmpresa());
                break;
        }
```

**SetarFiltrosEstoqueEmpresa():**

```
 public SqlParameter[] SetarFiltrosEstoqueEmpresa()
{
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@EmpInicial", txtEmpresaIni.Text),
            new SqlParameter("@EmpFinal", txtEmpresaFim.Text),
            new SqlParameter("@DataInicio", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDataIni.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
            new SqlParameter("@DataTermino", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDataFinal.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProdInicial.Text) ? new SqlParameter("@ProdInicial",DBNull.Value): new SqlParameter("@ProdInicial", txtProdInicial.Text)),
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProdFinal.Text) ? new SqlParameter("@ProdFinal", DBNull.Value): new SqlParameter("@ProdFinal", txtProdFinal.Text))
        };
        metodos.rpt = "SaldoEstoqueEmpresa.rpt";
        metodos.nomeFormula = new string[2];
        metodos.valorFormula = new string[2];         
        metodos.nomeFormula[0] = "Empresa";
        Empresa objEmpresa = new Empresa();
        if (objEmpresa.ConsultarEmpresa((string)Session["empresa"]) > 0) { metodos.valorFormula[0] = objEmpresa.ParEmpresa; }
        else { metodos.valorFormula[0] = string.Empty; }
        metodos.nomeFormula[1] = "Filtro";
        metodos.valorFormula[1] = "Produtos de " + txtProdInicial.Text + " à " + txtProdFinal.Text + " Periodo de " + txtDataIni.Text + " à " + txtDataFinal.Text;
        return param;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**ProcessarSaldoAtualEstoqueEmpresa():**

```
 public void ProcessarSaldoAtualEstoqueEmpresa(SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        try
        {
            strSql = new StringBuilder();
            strSql.Append("ProcSaldoEstoqueEmp");
            SqlDAO.executarSQLProc(strSql, param);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Método ExecutarProcSql:

```
        public static int executarSQLProc(StringBuilder strSql, params SqlParameter[] parametros)
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;
            con = abrirConexao();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql.ToString(), con);

            using (cmd)
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                int nRegs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return nRegs;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            fecharConexao(con);
        }
    }
```

Comment: qual o código do `SqlDAO.executarSQLProc(strSql, param);` ??

Comment: @RovannLinhalis os parametros "param" são setados no método `SetarFiltrosEstoqueEmpresa()`. Quando a proc for executada os dados ficariam assim exec `ProcSaldoEstoqueEmp '01','03','2017-05-01','2017-05-20','1003','1003'`

Comment: sim, isso aí acompanhei, quero saber o código do método `executarSQLProc`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Editei na pergunta

Comment: Não posso ver isso agora, mas recomendo tirar todos os `try-catch` do seu código, **eles só estão aumentando o problema**. Só os uso quando aprender como e quando usá-los. Zero `try-catch` não é bom, mas é um erro menor que colocar todos estes sem necessidade. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186617/101. Vi também um `StingBuilder` completamente desnecessário e ligeiramente prejudicial. Vejo outras coisas que poderiam estar melhores nesse código. Chamar `Dispose()` na mão dentro de `using` é erro, chamar `fecharConexao()` provavelmente é erro também.

Comment: Um dos motivos de eu não poder ajudar é que nem achei a *query*. No código novo da edição vi mais problemas.

Comment: aparentemente o código esta ok, siga os conselhos do bigown aí removendo esse monte de try-catch e poste também a query da procedure; A exceção está sendo lançada pelo código ou pelo banco ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis esta sendo lançado pelo código

Comment: em qual momento ? se tiver como mostrar a stack trace