# Tratar divisão por zero

Tags: php, matemática

Tenho a seguinte função em PHP:

```
public function teste() {
    $conta = "0/(0+0+0)";
    eval('$result = (' . $conta . ');');
    echo $result;
}
```

No caso, a fórmula (no exemplo 0/(0+0+0) obviamente volta erro por causa da divisão por zero. O problema é que esta fórmula é construída dinamicamente e pode ocorrer de acontecer divisão por zero. Neste caso gostaria que retornasse apenas zero e não o erro.

Comment: Se esses dados são dinamicos voce pode fazer uma verificação neles pra saber se são iguais a zero ou não, antes de fazer esse calculo.

Comment: poderia usar de exemplo: a/b+c+d, ficaria mais legivel....  `if (b+c+d = 0) echo '0' else ....calcula... ` !?

Comment: O grande problema é que a formula pode ter divisão ou não ter. O usuário consegue montar diversas fórmulas matemáticas.

Comment: Você valida a validade da fórmula? Ou simplesmente aceita qualquer string passada e deixa para dar problemas aritméticos na última instância? Por exemplo, essa fórmula seria inválida `(1 + 2 + 3*(123)`, pois falta parêntese.

Comment: Eu valido a expressão antes. Mas os valores não tenho como saber.

Comment: @FelipeSaraiva se você valida você está já compilando (as constantes eu pus só de exemplo). Se você está compilando, você pode montar a árvore de expressão e tratar ela internamente, de acordo com a ordem da precedência.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tem razão, vou partir para esta ideia, muito obrigado! Por gentileza, como faço para "aprovar" esta sugestão?

Comment: @FelipeSaraiva escreva uma resposta oficialmente. Estou com particular preguiça/falta de tempo para fazer uma resposta formal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiro, não deveria usar [`eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101). Tem que ter um domínio muito forte em programação para usá-lo sem problemas. E quem tem esse domínio sempre acha uma solução melhor.

[Divisão por zero é considerado um erro de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101), é a [mesma coisa que dar um erro de ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186670/101) (PHP não dá isso, acho, mas ele trata de forma que considero prejudicial), ele nunca deveria ocorrer, a solução é garantir que não ocorra a divisão por zero, então deve garantir que o divisor não seja zero antes de usá-lo. [Um simples `if` antes resolve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101). Mas neste caso nem precisa já que você sabe que é 0, não tem porque fazer isto em código real.

Sempre tratar a divisão por 0 como resultando em 0 é um erro matemático, se isto fosse correto a matemática faria isto. E quando fizer sentido por algum outro motivo que não o matemático está usando o número para uma função que ele não deve ter. Novamente, erros de programação não devem ser tratados como se fossem normais, ou como se fossem exceções.

Quando for capturar exceção, e em códigos bons isto raramente ocorre, [nunca capture `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101), esta exceção deveria até ser abstrata. Talvez tudo que serve para herdar deveria.

Veja também:

- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101)
- [O que são Exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88831/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Colocar um try / catch não seria a solução?

```
public function teste() {
    $conta = "0/(0+0+0)";
    try {
      eval('$result = (' . $conta . ');');
      echo $result;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
      echo 0;
    }    
}
```

Comment: funciona... mas se você pode checar se o valor é zero antes de calcular, porque disparar uma exception ?! ps. O -1 não fui eu =]

Comment: Acredito que não, pois na pergunta ele falou que era dinâmico a expressão, tipo uma calculadora.

Comment: entendi, ainda assim é possível checar, dá mais trabalho... rs mas é possível =]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, só uma compilaçãozinha básica ;-)

Comment: Uma baita complicação, rsss. Tentei esta solução mas ainda apresenta erro.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis correto, respondi sobre isso

Comment: @MarlonTiedt um erro não justifica o outro, ser dinâmico é o primeiro erro. Comete-se dois novos por causa dele.

Comment: @Maniero blz, sempre com respostas ótimas. Só não entendi o comentário "ser dinâmico é o primeiro erro". Exemplo: um sistema de laboratório, o usuário cadastra uma fórmula para validar o resultado de um exame. Logo a fórmula é dinâmica, estaria errado ?! é isso ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis a implmentação com `eval()` está, é inseguro e dá uma experiência péssima onde na prática que for cadastrar a fórmula precisa ser praticamente programador. Se tiver que fazer um recurso de cadastrar fórmula é necessário fazer uma mecanismo bem complexo e deve permitir indicar restrições de dados que esta fórmula deve ter, incluindo não dividir por 0. Claro, a pessoa pode fazer o que quiser, mas é uma enorme gambiarra simplificar o que é complexo por natureza. Tem uma solução bem mais simples.Ñ deixa a pessoa cadastrar fórmulas. Pode ser a melhor solução e melhor do que imaginam