# Como tratar divisão por 0

Tags: java, exceção

Tenho o código onde pode haver uma divisão por zero:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

conta = shell.evaluate(conta).toString();

txtConta.setText(conta);
```

Onde na 4ª linha, o método `evaluate(conta).toString();` retorna o resultado de uma expressão aritmética em **String**. Porém se tiver alguma divisão por 0, o programa fecha e lança a `ArithmeticException` justamente nessa mesma linha. Existe algum jeito de eu verificar se existe alguma divisão por 0 nesse trecho e apenas printar na tela uma **String** como "Erro: Divisão por 0" sem o programa crashar ?

Comment: Voce pode por o código dentro de um bloco Try Catch e no catch quando der a exception você lança a mensagem tratando ela, Informando que houve uma divisão por 0

Comment: Para ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1657925/6510304

Comment: Relacionada: [Tratar ArithmeticException em outro método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82279/28595)

Comment: Vale lembrar que esse GroovyShell é uma API de "terceiros".
Ela retorna alguns erros em suas próprias classes, porém a Exception lançada por ela é a mesma ArithmeticException, retornando a 4ª linha do exemplo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se não pode fazer a verificação no método mais interno, é possível capturar a exceção e fazer algo.

Creio eu que a melhor ideia é tratar isso no método mais interno, capturar a exceção deveria ser em último caso.

Exemplo:

```
try {
    conta = shell.evaluate(conta).toString();
}catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
    // Faça aqui a sua mensagem/tratamento do erro
}
```

Comment: Se fosse possível interceptar conta seria mais elegante, mas nem só de elegância vive o código

Comment: Acho que a API `GroovyShell` que lança a exceção. De qualquer forma, também acho mais interessante tratar no método mais interno.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode colocar dentro de um try catch esse trecho.

```
try{
    conta = shell.evaluate(conta).toString();
    txtConta.setText(conta);
} catch(ArithmeticException ex){
    txtConta.setText("Não divida por zero");
}
```